# Formatting decimal point for X,Y coordinates using R

Tags: r, coordinates, format, decimal-points

I am relatively new to R and GIS in general, but I am working with this dataset https://data.austintexas.gov/Public-Safety/AFD-Fire-Incidents-2016-January-Thru-December/5tib-gqfx

Whoever created it, put the Lat/Long in the same column without decimal points, and degrees, and made it a character vector.
I've used the following R script to separate the columns into lat and long:

```s
AFD_2014 <- read_csv("/Users/olive/Documents/AFD_Fire_Incidents_2014_January_Thru_December copy.csv")
AFD_2014
AFD_2014 <- separate(AFD_2014, col = Location1, into = c("Location1", "Location2"), sep = ",\\s")
AFD_2014$Location1 <- str_replace(AFD_2014$Location1, "\\(", "")
AFD_2014$Location2 <- str_replace(AFD_2014$Location2, "\\)", "")
AFD_2014
names(AFD_2014)[names(AFD_2014) == "Location1"] <- "Longitude"
AFD_2014
names(AFD_2014)[names(AFD_2014) == "Location2"] <- "Latitude"
AFD_2014
AFD_2014$Latitude <- as.numeric(AFD_2014$Latitude)
AFD_2014$Longitude <- as.numeric(AFD_2014$Longitude)
```

But, I have not been able to figure out how I can insert a decimal period in between, for example "30345401" to make it "30.345401", THAT'S MY GOAL.
Things I've tried

- Excel, *Copy*, *Paste Special*, *Multiply*
- Excel Format cells, Custom
- R gsub
- R `format(round(x, #), nsmall = #)`

Answer (score 3):

The data is in latitude, longitude order, you are assigning them in the wrong order.

According to the metadata on [the page you linked to](https://data.austintexas.gov/Public-Safety/AFD-Fire-Incidents-2016-January-Thru-December/5tib-gqfx):

> Latitude = non-decimal latitude. Please use this formula to calculate for GIS geolocating = latitude *0.000001
>
> Longitude = non-decimal longitude. Please use this formula to
> calculate for GIS geolocating = longitude * -.000001

So since you already cast them as numbers (`as.numeric`) just multiply lat by 0.000001 and lon by -0.000001

Comment: Thank you, that worked. It's still not projecting onto the map, and the lat/long formula appears reversed from the x,y coordinates I have for a shapefile in the same area. So I'm thinking I'll have to contact the dataset owner and ask for some more details on this

Comment: Probably lat/lon order not lon/lat. That's very common.

Comment: Yes! and I ended up finding out the formula was mismatched for the lat//lon as well.

Comment: No, the formula is correct for lat, lon. You want positive latitudes and negative longitudes for Austin e.g. 30.3, -97.8